# GNU Radio Block run code on program termination

Tags: c++, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am writing a gnuradio sink block for custom SDR hardware. When the gnuradio program is closed, I need to make sure that the power amplifiers are disabled (as they draw quite a bit of power and produce a lot of heat). I tried doing this with a class destructor thinking it would be called upon program termination, however it was not. Does gnuradio provide a way to run cleanup upon program termination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overload the [`stop`](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1block.html#a0863bc16f7c84adf4cddf5d53124450e) method of the  `gr::block` base class. It's meant for exactly that!

Answer (score 1):

Example of overriding in Python: if you insert a Python block, add the `stop` method like so:

```py
class blk(gr.sync_block):
    def __init__(self):
        # omitted...

    def work(self):
        # omitted...

    def stop(self):
        print "do stopping work here"
        return True
```

Notes:

- <s>I don't know what the return value is used for.</s> (*Answered in comments -- thanks!*)
- In my experimentation, it appears that `stop` does not run for blocks that lack inputs and outputs.

Comment: blocks that aren't part of the flow graph don't "run", they only exist (you might have nothing from the fact they're blocks – maybe you'd just want a normal Python class of sorts?). So, that `stop` isn't run if your block isn't connected to something is no surprise!

Comment: the return value of stop() is currently unused.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Isn't the block's `__init__` run always (even for blocks that are not part of the flow graph)?

Comment: `__init__` is the constructor. Whenever you instantiate an object of your class, the constructor is called – this is python, not GNU Radio-related.